# How do I obtain a Long-lived User Token using the Facebook Python SDK?

Tags: python, facebook

How do I obtain a Long-lived User Token using the Facebook Python SDK? I'm currently copying and pasting the User Token from the page https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/ but I would like to be able to obtain the User Token programatically using the Facebook Python SDK using ONLY Code. I don't want to have a dialog box because I'm making a server-to-server request.

Comment: I'm not sure if it still like this... But... 2 years ago I had to do a server request to Facebook API with the short life token for extending it to 60 days.
They had an API for token extending requests.

Comment: If your SDK doesn’t provide a ready-made method for this, it is easy enough to implement yourself – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending describes what steps are necessary to extend an access token.